# export 'LOCATION_INITIALIZED' was not found in '@angular/common'

Tags: angular

My angular 2 app was working nicely until this morning when I started VS and was greeted with this error message

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/router/src/router_module.js
303:51-71 "export 'LOCATION_INITIALIZED' was not found in '@angular/common'
```

and the following as well

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Token must be defined! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Token must be defined!
at new ReflectiveKey (reflective_key.js:36) [angular]
at KeyRegistry.get (reflective_key.js:89) [angular]
at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (reflective_key.js:54) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:325) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:140) [angular]
at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (router_module.js:303) [angular]
at new ApplicationInitStatus (application_init.js:30) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:597) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (ng_module_factory.js:123) [angular]
at NgModuleFactory.create (ng_module_factory.js:91) [angular]
at :8080/dist/app.bundle.js:47522:61 [angular]
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:273) [angular] Error: Token must be defined!
at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:49098:19) [angular]
at KeyRegistry.get (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:49151:39) [angular]
at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:49116:35) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:130453:102) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:69771:52) [angular]
at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:82228:48) [angular]
at new ApplicationInitStatus (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:47099:45) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:597:36) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:69754:76) [angular]
at NgModuleFactory.create (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:69722:18) [angular]
at http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:47522:61 [angular]
at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8080/dist/app.bundle.js:36376:37) angular]
consoleError @ zone.js:405
zone.js:407 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!
Error: Token must be defined!
at new ReflectiveKey (reflective_key.js:36) [angular]
at KeyRegistry.get (reflective_key.js:89) [angular]
at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (reflective_key.js:54) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:325) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:140) [angular]
at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (router_module.js:303) [angular]
at new ApplicationInitStatus (application_init.js:30) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:597) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (ng_module_factory.js:123) [angular]
at NgModuleFactory.create (ng_module_factory.js:91) [angular]
at :8080/dist/app.bundle.js:47522:61 [angular]
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:273) [angular]
at new ReflectiveKey (reflective_key.js:36) [angular]
at KeyRegistry.get (reflective_key.js:89) [angular]
at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (reflective_key.js:54) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:325) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:140) [angular]
at RouterInitializer.appInitializer (router_module.js:303) [angular]
at new ApplicationInitStatus (application_init.js:30) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.createInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:597) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.create (ng_module_factory.js:123) [angular]
at NgModuleFactory.create (ng_module_factory.js:91) [angular]
at :8080/dist/app.bundle.js:47522:61 [angular]
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:273) [angular]
at resolvePromise (zone.js:486) [<root>]
at :8080/dist/polyfills.bundle.js:18027:17 [<root>]
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151) [<root> => <root>]
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:418) [<root>]
```

The application compiles and the problem surfaces during runtime. I am using angular 2 with typescript 2.1.6

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is having this issue, the latest release of @angular/router (3.4.0) is incompatible with other angular 2 dependencies, rolling back to 3.3.0 resolves the issue. This is sadly an all too familiar experience...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it working again. On start up of VS it did do some updates to some packages. So I took out the entire node_module folder and made sure I had the appropriate package versions and the reinstallation restored everything

Comment: any idea what the appropriate packages were?

Comment: Yeah it turns out I had a mixture of "~,^" prefixing the package versions while some packages had no prefixes at at all. so after the update I had the package versions mismatching. So I prefixed all the version number with "~" and deleted the node_module folder relaunched VS.